# How to initialize a trait variable that is a val

Tags: scala, accessor, traits

I have MyObject and MyTrait:

```
class MyObject(private val myname: String = "") extends MyTrait {

  _name = myname

  def foo(myname : String) {
   _name = myname
  }
}

trait MyTrait {

  protected var _name: String = _

  def name = _name

}
```

This works fine as this

```
val myObject = new MyObject("abc")
println(myObject.name)
myObject.foo("def")
println(myObject.name)
```

prints

```
abc
def
```

as expected.

Problem now is that I want MyTrait._name to be a val instead of a var. But there is no way I can manage to get this to compile. Any hints appreciated.

Regards, Oliver

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone attempting to approach this problem, you want `_name` to be a val, and you want the `name` property to be mutated by `foo`, right?  See the style guide link in my answer and the ML discussion on why underscore can be confusing in var names.

Comment: @som-snytt: the foo method was a left-over I should have removed before pasting the sample code. That val is not writeable is at least something I knew ;-)

Comment: @OliverPlow: You can remove the foo-method right now, if it is superflous/distubing.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an answer that uses the very latest cutting-edge naming conventions from Rex Kerr and Martin Odersky!

Read it on [the scala-debate list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/CzlQg-TCKbA).  And you thought they sit around working on "higher kinds" and computing with unboxed ints.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/pull/215) for the style changes, but this convention will have to wait a bit.

Doc Martin says: `That does look promising. I have to experiment with it a little.`

So be careful with this stuff; it's experimental and probably chemically unstable.

```
class MyObject(override protected val initialName: String = "") extends MyTrait {

  private var myName: String = initialName

  def name_=(newName: String) {
    myName = newName
  }
  override def name = myName
}

trait MyTrait {
  protected val initialName: String = "default"
  def name = initialName
}
object Test extends App {
  val myObject = new MyObject("abc")
  println(myObject.name)
  myObject.name = "def"
  println(myObject.name)
}
```

[The style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) has a section on brevity but is itself not brief.  I'm sure there are answers on SO about "prefer def over val in traits" by Daniel Sobral. And don't forget to consult [the one-question FAQ](https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki) when you encounter init-order problems.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Only thing is I don't understand why they don't talk about having propper properties in Scala as in Groovy/Kotlin/Ruby. Instead things are "fixed" by sticking to conventions.

Comment: People talk about it (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2094) and there's BeanProperty annotation if you lean that way. The style guide offers some guidance in fact (http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html under accessors). Basically, as repeated ad nauseum, uniform access principle.